# selecting in vb.net with ms access database

Tags: vb.net, select

I want to select some data in my table and I use this code :

```
Public Class frmLogin
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
            Dim t As New DataTable
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
    Dim tuser As String = txtUsername.Text

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM dosen WHERE nip=tuser"
    Try
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read
            MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0).ToString & _
                            vbTab & vbTab & reader.GetString(1).ToString)
        End While
    Finally
        If reader IsNot Nothing Then reader.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

But there is an error in `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()` line. Anyone can help me?

Comment: where is ur connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the mistakes. The code should be

```
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader ' no need for nothing
Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM dosen WHERE nip='" & tuser & "'"
```

tuser is a variable, not the content